# How to transfer json data to html with php?

Tags: php, json

How to transfer json data to html with php?

```
$url="http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=usa&rank=newest&api-key=mykey"
```

when I type the url in browser, it return
`{"offset" : "0" , "results" : [{"body" : "A guide to cultural and recreational goings-on in and around the Hudson Valley. ...}]}`
how to put the json `body` data into html? I mean like this `echo '<div class="body"></div>';`

Comment: From where are you calling the URL? Client side (JavaScript) or server side (PHP) ?

Comment: Your question is really vague, can you expand on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to get the file. You should use curl for this. In the example below I used the `file_get_contents()` function, you might want to replace it. Use `json_decode()` to parse the JSON for you.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->results[0]->body;
```

This will echo `A guide to cultural...`.

Comment: this can echo the `body`, but if there have 10 items, I shall write `echo $data->results[0]->body;`, `echo $data->results[1]->body;` ... ? thanks.

Comment: Yep. Or use `foreach ($data->results as $result) { echo $result->body; }` to echo all "bodies".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get all the `$result->body`

Comment: If you want to put your JSON data onto a web page, you may use client side scripting such as JavaScript. e.g.: `document.getElementById("<id-of-your-div>").innerHTML = <json-body>` (If you use jQuery this will be lot easier).

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_decode()` on the content of the file, which you can retrieve with `file_get_contents($url)`, then you have an array you can use to build the HTML.

```
$url="http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=usa&rank=newest&api-key=mykey";
$dataRaw = file_get_contents($url);

if ($dataRaw) {
  $data = json_decode($dataRaw, true);
  foreach ($data['results'] as $cEntry) {
?>
  <div class="body">
      <?php echo $cEntry['body']; ?>
  </div>
<?php
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, @Orbling, but some wrong echo `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` on line ` foreach ($data['results'] as $cEntry) {`

Comment: @cj333: Sorry, stupid PHP does not make JSON arrays in to actual arrays by default.  You have to specify the second parameter as true to `json_decode()` to get it to do so.  Edited the code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would, but assuming `fopen()` URL opening is enabled, you could do...

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
<?php

$url="http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=usa&rank=newest&api-key=mykey";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is not a good option to get data from external URLs as it cannot handle timeouts or operate behind proxies. Use `cURL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've loaded a JSON string into PHP, you can then convert it into a PHP array by using the function `json_decode()`. You can then print the appropriate array element into your HTML output as with any other PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($yourJsonEncodedData);
echo $jsonDecoded->results->body;
```