# Dispaly jQuery.getJSON 's response data as html

Tags: jquery, jsp, getjson

I need to dynamically create two select box. I am using the following code

```
function getAvailableArticlePages()
{
var maga_arti_id=jQuery('#new_article_id').val();
jQuery.getJSON("/admin/availablearticlepages.do?method=getArticlesAvailablePage"
,{maga_arti_id: ""+maga_arti_id+""}, function(data){    
jQuery('#pages td#leftpage select').html(data.Options);
jQuery('#pages td#rightpage select').html(data.Option1);
});        
}
```

in the response JSP page i am using the following code

```
Options+="<option value=\""+page_id+"\">"+page_name+"</option>";
Options1+="<option value=\""+page_id+"\">"+page_name+"</option>";
out.print("{\"Options\":");
out.print("\""+Options+"\"");   
out.print(",\"Options1\":");
out.print("\""+Options1+"\"");  
out.print("}");
```

but it is not creating html select box options. Can any one say how to response html code as itself in jquery.getjson() method what should be the content type at the JSP

Thanks in advance 
tony

Comment: What do you get instead? What do you have in the network tab after the ajax call? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Probably an escaping issue. Insert a `console.log(data)` in the getJSON callback function and view it in a browser with a console.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you need to pass the HTML as a JSON object?

Have a look at the jQuery function [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

This should be able to load the options straight into the select element as HTML.

If you need to load two separate select box's with different options then either do two separate queries or make one query that returns the HTML for two select box's and their options.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i agree with you now i am using those type of technique. is there any way to get HTML code as JSON object. Content type have any role in that??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646155/584501 shows how its done in PHP and you should be able to find a JSP equivalent to json_encode in one of the java libraries listed at http://json.org/

Comment: As @Thomas said the problem with your first solution is probably escaping the double quotes correctly. Either use a library like I mentioned or have a look at the raw return value and try to correct it.

Comment: out.print("{\"Options\":");
     out.print("\""+Options+"\"");   
     out.print(",\"Options1\":");
     out.print("\""+Options1+"\"");  
     out.print("}");       this is the code for displaying it. and i also try data.Options.html at callback the control did'nt come at call back